# Firewall Types ( OS and Software )

Tags: firewall

what is the difference between OS firewall  and  software firewall  ?
 i searched a lot but i didn't find a good answer any idea please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An OS firewall is the built in one that comes with your OS like Windows Firewall.

A software firewall is one that you buy separately, such as Norton Firewall or something like that.

I would have expected the question to be what the difference between a hardware and software firewall are.

Answer (score 0):

An OS firewall is the one that comes with your OS like Windows Firewall.

A software firewall is one that you download separately, such as Norton Firewall...